# Is it possible to use Series Tests for Improper Integrals?

Tags: definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I saw this solution to a problem on twitter, and the solution seems to of used the direct comparison test for the improper integral. I asked my professor about it, but they replied with "yes, just make sure to follow the given conditions." However, they didn't mention what conditions we would need to follow.

If we can use Series Tests for Improper Integrals, how would we go about using them?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qy3HE.jpg)

Comment: You can prove a version of Direct Comparison with integrals by the monotonicity of the integral.